# Disable android secure keyguard programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have an app with an alarm. When alarm trigger the app loads with the following code:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    setShowWhenLocked(true);
    setTurnScreenOn(true);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
} else {
    getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

but I want to remove the locker screen after exit my app. If is a non secure keyguard works well but with a secure keyguard after exit app I have to insert the keyguard pattern. There's any way to remove the secure keyguard or this code only works for a non secure keyguard? 
I'm testing in a Samsung Galaxy with android pie.

Answer (score 0):

You can only request a dismissal but if it's secured, it would ask the user to unlock it. Also, we shouldn't be allowed to do that (it can act as a vulnerability, imagine a thief-developer who creates an app with location permission and the feature you're seeking. He tracks victims using the app and can unlock their phones by the app and do whatever he wants).
Also you can use `KeyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard()` to achieve the same thing you're facing right now (just a bit more standard)